# RXJS dependent observables

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have 3 observables:

```
query$: Observable<string> = this.q$.pipe(tap(() => this.page$.next(0));
filter$: Observable<number> = this.f$.pipe(tap(() => this.page$.next(0));
page$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

combinetLatest({
  query: this.query$,
  filter: this.filter$,
  page: this.page$
})
.pipe(
  switchMap(({ query, filter, page }) => {
    ...
  })
);
```

I have to pass their values down the stream whenever any of them emit. However, using `combineLatest` results in at least two more redundant emits. I attempted to wire in `distinctUntilChanged()`, but this also produces one redundant emit at some point.

Please assist :( or perhaps my entire approach/thinking is incorrect, and I should not change `page$` as a side-effect of `query$`, `filter$`?

**Update**: <s>In a sense, I don't care about the "page" value, as it's always 0 in the case of "query" or "filter" emissions. But I do care about "query" and "filter" values when "page" emits. So it seems that it becomes two separate observables?.. But I wanted to assign it to a component property in order to use it with the "async" pipe in the template, so with two different observables, I can't...</s>

**Update**: Sorry for the fuss; I should have specified more details.
The `query$` is being emitted on input field input.
The `filter$` is being emitted on select box changes.
The `page$`, which stands for "page number," is being emitted on the "Load More" button click.

So my idea was to have a component property:

```
objects$: Observable<object[]> = combineLatest({
  query: this.query$,
  filter: this.filter$,
  page: this.page$
}).pipe(
  switchMap(({ query, filter, page }) => this.someService.sendApiRequest(query, filter, page)),
  scan((acc, { objects}) => {
    if (page !== 0) {
      return [...acc, ...objects];
    } else {
      return objects;
    }
  }, [])
);
```

And use it in a template with the `async` pipe:

```
<div *ngFor="let x of objects$ | async">...</div>
```

Basically, to fetch results whenever the user types in a query, changes filters, or loads more items.

Comment: I would recommend to use `switchMap` operator for your case.

Comment: You're probably looking for a debounce of some kind in addition to the distinctUntilChanged

Comment: I am confused about the `page$`. Why it is a side-effect of `query$` and `filter$`. 

I assume that you want to emit a page$ value when a query or filter is emitted. If not I want to know when page$ will emit value.

Comment: @truonghungit, I clarified the case. "page" is a side-effect because if we do not reset it after the query/filter has changed and emit "page" again, it will load incorrect page for the latest "query/filter"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would work:

```js
combineLatest({ query: this.q$, filter: this.f$ }).pipe(
  switchMap(({query, filter}) => this.page$.pipe(
    map((p, i) => i === 0 ? 0 : p)),
    map(page => ({query, filter, page}))
  ))
);
```

The idea is that your combineLatest starts with only the `query` and the `filter`, then switchMaps to the `page`.  The second argument in the `map` operator indicates the "emission index" of the subscription to `page$`, which will start at 0, and increase each time `page$` emits.  So, we emit `0` when it's the first emission and emit the value from `page$` after that.  Whenever either the `filter$` or `query$` emit, the switchMap will create a new subscription, which means the a new inner subscription to `page$` is made meaning the index will start back at 0.

You could tack on another `switchMap` to make your api call or just turn the second `map` into `switchMap`:

```js
combineLatest({ query: this.q$, filter: this.f$ }).pipe(
  switchMap(({query, filter}) => this.page$.pipe(
    map((p, i) => i === 0 ? 0 : p)),
    switchMap(page => this.callApi(query, filter, page))
  ))
);
```

---

Update:

If you don't need to specify an actual page number and only need the next page to load, instead of `page$` you can use:

```js
private loadMore$ = new BehaviorSubject<void>(undefined);
```

And your observable for the view could look like:

```js
items$ = combineLatest({ query: this.q$, filter: this.f$ }).pipe(
  switchMap(({query, filter}) => this.loadMore$.pipe(
    switchMap((_, page) => this.callApi(query, filter, page)),
    scan((all, items) => all.concat(items), [])
  )),
);
```

Here we simply use `loadMore$` as a trigger, and use the "emission index" of the inner observable as the page number. Since `loadMore$` is a BehaviorSubject, it will emit once upon subscription, so it doesn't require a button click to emit the first time. Then each subsequent time `loadMore$` emits (*when your button is clicked*), it will emit again and switchMap will execute the api call with the incremented index (*page number*).

Here's a [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-77679905?devtoolsHeight=50&file=src%2Fapp%2Fapi.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: That is interesting, thanks, but it seems that this will ignore "page$" emissions?

Comment: it will only ignore the first one.  After that it will use the value emitted from `page$`.  After reading your updates though, it seems you don't really need to emit a number, you just need the next page to load, so we can simplify a bit.

Comment: Wow! You showed me how switchMap actually works!

Answer (score 0):

So, which of your observables do you prefer to emit immediately, and which ones should you just know their values? Take your main observable, and then add two others with the [`withLatestFrom`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/withlatestfrom) operator just to accept data, but not emit your root source. As a result, your stream will only be called by one, but will accept two additional data along with it

Comment: There are two main observables: "page" and the combination of "query" and "filter." So I guess in the case of "page$" being main, I have to go withLatestFrom(combineLatest(query$, filter$)); and in the case of the combineLatest(query$, filter$) being main, I have to go withLatestFrom(page$). But I wanted to assign it to a component property in order to use it with the "async" pipe in the template, so with two different observables, I can't...

Comment: Than use `this.page$.pipe(withLatestFrom(this.query$, this.filter$))` and in each page emit you'll collect page value with additional query and filter values, but at the same time, query and filter stream never emit your Observer

Comment: I clarified the case. Basically I would like to listen for any of 3 observables, and pass down all 3 latest values...